# What does a lag of 2N mean in autocorrelation?

Tags: time-series, correlation

From what I understand, when performing auto-correlation we compute the correlation of a signal with its own shifted version at different shift times (1,2 ..) which is referred as the lag. Now if my original signal has N points for lag 1, I am computing the correlation between two signals of length N-1 and for lag 2 it will be N-2.

In many studies I see auto-correlations with lag values going up to two times the original signal, meaning if your measured signal has N points the resulted auto-correlation graph has 2xN points on the x axis (lag). I was wondering how can this happen if when we perform autocorrelation at lag=N the original signal is finished by then because the copied signal has been shifted N time now! Does that mean that the original signal has been extended after point N with zero values up to 2xN point?

Comment: Having one lag does not necessarily include the whole signal. This is true for a random walk where including more/longer information from the past does not bring any „new“ insights. However, with other time series, longer lags can be helpful. E.g. two times „down“ is different from „up“, „down“ or the like.

Comment: @Peter not sure if I understand your point. What I am saying is how computationally is that possible?

Comment: Can you please clarify the second paragraph of your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @fractalnature: Tried to explain better now, the second paragraph is edited.